# Zend Framework ORDER BY

Tags: zend-framework

I have a list of items that I want to order in alphabetical order, heres my code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->authoriseUser();
    $this->view->assign('title', 'Clubs');
    $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title, 'PREPEND');
    $clubs = new Application_Model_DbTable_Clubs();
    $this->view->clubs = $clubs->fetchAll();
    $select = $clubs->select();
    $select->order('club_name ASC');
}
```

Whats wrong? As it doesn't work..

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the select object to the fetchAll method

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->authoriseUser();
    $this->view->assign('title', 'Clubs');
    $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title, 'PREPEND');
    $clubs = new Application_Model_DbTable_Clubs();
    $select = $clubs->select()
        ->order('club_name ASC');
    $this->view->clubs = $clubs->fetchAll($select);
}
```